# Is it possible to have a Master "master project" in MSProj10- that is to have a subproject that has its own subprojects?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I want to have a Grandmaster of a complex project - that is one that is has subprojects which themselves are made up of subprojects.  Will that work in MSProj10

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  (All subject to the same caveats that cover individual linked sub-projects.)  I have successfully manipulated 4-tier multi-projects for testing purposes - (not in Project Server.)

Successful implementation of multiple linked sub-projects in the real world will demand rigorous procedural controls to avoid a tangled mess of invalid links.  In my experience, it is easier to either 1) Implement a single integrated project schedule with many internal links and shared access (with procedural controls) or 2)Implement multiple independent projects that can be merged into a single (unlinked) master project periodically for integrated reporting.

Comment: Tom - thanks for the input and voice of experience.  I am gonna go w door number 2 (merge them only if and when).  All the best

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the feedback.  Note, merging and de-merging can be automated with macros, though I don't think they are freeware. Check with "John - Project" on Technet.  In addition, Eric Uyttewaal (ProjectPro.com) sells an add-in for inserting/deleting and otherwise managing cross-project links.